# How to copy from couple folders back to the current directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just came to an interesting question in Linux. I want to find a shortcut for copying from multiple folder back in the path to the current path. For example:

```
A/B/C/D/E> cp ../../../example.txt .
```

I want to see if there is any shortcut for the above command, instead of typing .. couple of times.

Comment: A shortcut for what? For copying from exactly 3 folders above your current directory? Are you looking for something more general or you need specifically 3?

Comment: `if there is any shortcut for the above command` - No.

Answer (score -1):

Bash is great... try something like this:

```
for dir in dir_one dir_two dir_three/path; do cp some.file $dir; done
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; That's not a shortcut for something like `cp ../../../example.txt .`